# Does expiration of iPhone Developer Program put any affect on existing apps on AppStore ?

Tags: iphone, itunes

My iPhone Developer Program has expired and now i am no longer able to access iTunes Portal. And also, one my application on App Sore has started giving the error that "this application is no longer available, ...".

I just want to ask that does expiration of the developer account put any affect on existing apps on App Store or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, your apps are no longer available when your membership is expired. But if you sign up again they should come right back.

Comment: Sign up means renew the membership and than my apps will be available again for distribution.